# Failed to resolve import "./schemas" from "sanity.config.ts". Does the file exist

Tags: javascript, sanity, hyper

I tried removing the dot and / but still nothing is happening.

[screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDIMB.png)

i think the file is in the wrong location. but i dont know where should it be.

Comment: Are you sure that this file is in the correct location?

Comment: What do you mean
sorry im new to this

Comment: You have imported schemaTypes `import {schemaTypes} from 'schemas/schema.js'` as named import. What does your `schema.js` looks like? If it contains `export default` you should remove `{ }` from the import. So it looks like: `import schemaTypes from 'schemas/schema.js`

Comment: I have tried to do that also but it  doesnt work... i think the file is in the wrong location

Comment: Please share the contents of the sanitys parent directory. 
Make sure your bundler is not expecting a .js file automatically. Try putting  .ts at the end of the import

Comment: i added a picture on my post, i hope it helps!

Comment: This should work ‘@/schemas/schema.js’

Comment: It still doesnt work..

Comment: import schemaTypes from "all:part:@sanity/base/schema-type"; 
maybe is something wrong with this